# Can I include helper method in service object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I defined a helper method: `MembersHelper`

```
module MembersHelper
 def current_segment
   Segment.where(current: true).first
 end
end
```

then included it in a class call Base in `app/service/enum_data/base.rb` file

```
module EnumData   
  class Base
    include MembersHelper   
  end
end
```

And used it from Base's subclass: GetAll in `app/service/enum_data/get_all.rb` file

```
module EnumData
  class GetAll < Base
    def self.call
      reference_data = current_segment.entities.all
    end
  end
end
```

But I got an error

`undefined local variable or method 'current_segment' for EnumData::GetByCategory:Class`

I fixed it by moving `current_segment` method to Base class, but I want to know why it doesn't work when I include that helper method? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are using `include`, which makes `current_segment` an *instance method* in the including classes while what you need, is a *class instance method* (singleton method). In order to achieve it you should use `extend`:

```
module EnumData   
  class Base
    extend MembersHelper   
  end
end
```